# What does a question mark mean in PHP function parameter's default value?

Tags: php, function, syntax, parameters

There is a question mark in a parameter's default value for functions in PHP documentation. E.g.:

```
 assert(mixed $assertion, string $description = ?): bool
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php

What does it mean?

Comment: The `?` indicates an optional parameter in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the parameter is optional and has a dynamic default value. Usually, optional parameters have default values that are static, like this:

```
foo (string $bar = null): bool
```

Or this:

```
foo (string $bar = 0): bool
```

But in some cases, the default value changes depending on environment. These are shown by a question mark:

```
assert(mixed $assertion, string $description = ?): bool
```

And then the description of the parameter will tell you more details about what the exact value is:

> From PHP 7, if no description is provided, a default description equal to the source code for the invocation of assert() is provided.

Comment: Is there any documentation about this syntax?  It's not a PHP function syntax, so I can't write my own function with default value set to '?'?

Comment: Correct, it's not an actual language feature, it's just a convention used in the documentation. Think of it as a shortcut meaning "see details below" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The `$description` argument is optional, but its default value is not a constant. The manual explains:

> From PHP 7, if no description is provided, a default description equal to the source code for the invocation of `assert()` is provided.

This can't be easily expressed in the syntax summary, so they used `?` as a placeholder.

Comment: It's not a PHP function syntax, so I can't write my own function with default value set to '?'?

Comment: No, it's a documentation convention, not PHP syntax.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php

> assert() is a language construct in PHP 7

So it's not a function syntax. You can't use such a syntax in your own function.

Other answers are right about meaning of the question mark in the description of assert().
But the essence of the answer is **"assert() is not a function"**, so my question is wrong by itself as it refers assert() as  a function.
Thanks for hints!